# Не запускается проект на битриксе

Tags: php, битрикс

После выгрузки проекта на локальный сервак перестал запускаться проект.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, что стоит в .settings.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что в dbconn.php
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На сколько помню, нужно указать в 2х файлах параметры подключения к БД ( `bitrix/.settings.php` и `bitrix/php_interface/dbconn.php`) там должны быть правильно указаны хост, БД, логин и пароль к БД. После чего в админке битрикса поправить путь к корневым файлам сайта.

Comment: Если у вас php7 - то в нем нет расширения `mysql`. Надо использовать `mysqli`.

Comment: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/messages/forum6/topic64195/message482409/#message482409

Answer (score 0):

Нужно правильно произвести настройку к подключение к БД на этапе установки. Но если вы пропустили этот момент то попробуйте настроить dbconn.php таким образом:

```js
if ( $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1' ) {
 define( "DBName", 'bitrix' );
 define( "DBHost", 'localhost' );
 define( "DBLogin", 'root' );
 define( "DBPassword", '' );
} else {
 define( "DBName", 'db_name' );
 define( "DBHost", 'db_host' );
 define( "DBLogin", 'admin' );
 define( "DBPassword", 'admin' );
}
define("BX_USE_MYSQLI", true);
define("DBPersistent", false);
$DBType = "mysql";
$DBHost = "localhost";
$DBLogin = "mysql";
$DBPassword = "mysql";
$DBName = "sitemanager";

$DBDebug = false;
$DBDebugToFile = false;
```